# Как заполнить динамический массив при инициализации?

Tags: c++

Создаю динамический массив так:

```
int *size = new int(10);
int *mas = new int[*size];
```

Нужно при инициализации заполнить его значениями `{-2, 2, 5, 3, -2, -1, 7, 8, 2, 6}`
То есть заполнить как статический массив `int mas[10] = {-2, 2, 5, 3, -2, -1, 7, 8, 2, 6}`

Как это сделать?

Comment: Главный вопрос - вы пишете на C++ или на С - с классами? Разные языки - разные подходы. Один тег лишний - уберите или C++ или C. И если речь идет о C++, то какой из стандартов - 98, 11 или 14? В данном вопросе, это важно.

Comment: Пишу на C++. Стандарт, видимо, 98

Comment: Если учите, вам понадобятся как старые (98), так и новые стандарты.

Comment: У вас во второй строчке ошибка: вы получите массив mas размером в 1 int. Вообще там чуть посложнее, и вы можете на малых размерах ошибку и не получить, но потом обязательно наступите на грабли.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для c++ это не очень хороший тон, лучше использовать std::vector, а еще лучше в данном случае, если массив не изменяется (по длине) использовать std::array.

C/C++:

```
static int val[] = {-2, 2, 5, 3, -2, -1, 7, 8, 2, 6};
int *size = new int(sizeof(val) / sizeof(int));
int *mas = new int[*size];
for (size_t i = 0; i < *size; ++i)
{
  mas[i] = val[i];
}
```

C/C++: (Вариант с временным массивом вместо статического)

```
int *size = 0; // в C++11 size = nullptr;
int *mas = 0; // в C++11 mas = nullptr;  
{
  int val[] = {-2, 2, 5, 3, -2, -1, 7, 8, 2, 6};
  size = new int(sizeof(val) / sizeof(int))
  mas = new int[sizeof(val) / sizeof(int)];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(val) / sizeof(int); ++i)
  {
    mas[i] = val[i];
  }
}
```

C++11:

```
int *size = new int(10); // Лучше так не делать!!!
int *mas = new int[*size];
int index = 0;
for (auto i : {-2, 2, 5, 3, -2, -1, 7, 8, 2, 6})
{
  mas[index++] = i;
}
```

C++11:

```
std::vector<int> mas = {-2, 2, 5, 3, -2, -1, 7, 8, 2, 6};
std::array<int, 10> mas = {-2, 2, 5, 3, -2, -1, 7, 8, 2, 6};
```

В первых трех примерах код кривоват, но это больше си чем с++. Рекомендую использовать stl. Еще вместо циклов можно использовать `memcpy`.

UPD: Поправил с учетом комментариев.

Comment: Маленькое уточнение "не изменяется" в контексте std::array означает - по длине не изменяется. Содержимое std::array можно изменять как угодной.

Comment: Вы притащили ошибку из исходного кода. Для корректировки имеет смысл поменять местами создание массива mas и статического val, и создавать mas как int *mas = new int[sizeof(val)/sizeof(int)];. Сейчас же mas инициализируется как new int[1] (если мне не изменяет склероз в плане синтаксиса создания динамических переменных).

Comment: memcpy - это такое приведение из мира C. Уж если копировать, то std::copy

Comment: Ну тогда уж доработайте ещё чуть — во втором случае можно создать как int *size = new int(10);, в первом — int *size = new int(sizeof(val)/sizeof(int));, как-то так. Заодно автор усвоит разницу между конструктором и созданием массива :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int * p = new int [5] { 1, 0, 3, 0, 5 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        std::cout << p[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

C++11

Answer (score 2):

Самым быстрым будет иметь статический массив с нужными значениями, а затем делать копию из него во вновь созданный динамический массив.

Comment: Нужно именно без статических массивов, чтобы иметь потом возможность полностью удалить массив

Comment: @RichardWatson в любом случае, программа должна где-то помнить эти значения. Так что либо вы храните их в статическом массиве и тиражируете, либо изобретаете хитрую формулу f(i) (погуглите про полином Лагранжа), чтобы затем бегать по ней циклом, заполняя массив.